# How to send the file using curl in php

Tags: php, curl, cakephp, pdf-conversion

I had tried to send the file for pdf conversion using curl., but i got error from API side.

```
    $file_name_with_full_path = WWW_ROOT . "img/IPG_07_12_2020.xlsx";
    if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
      $cFile = curl_file_create($file_name_with_full_path);
    } else { 
      $cFile = '@' . realpath($file_name_with_full_path);
    }

    $post = array('file_contents'=> curl_file_create($file_name_with_full_path));
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:3000/convert/office",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 86400,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>$post,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'),
    ));

    
    
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
```

and the error was {"message":"context has timed out"}.,
please share your knowledge to send the file to curl in proper way.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what happens when you remove `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 86400`?

Comment: i got same result if remove or add.

Comment: What does the problem have to do with sending files? Does sending requests without files work? What API are you talking about (ie what is running at `localhost:3000/convert/office`)? Have you checked the logs of the API application? How is CakePHP involved in this?